# Characterizing the boundary of image of $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, manifolds, differential-topology, jacobian

**Note:** The original question asked how to prove that $f$ maps interior points to interior points when it has a positive Jacobian. This was a silly question as it's an immediate consequence of the Inverse Function Theorem as pointed out in the comment. I modified the question to better reflect the true nature of the issue.

Consider a differentiable map $f$ with positive definite Jacobian:
$$f(x,y):\Omega = [0,\infty)\times Y\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^{m+1}, \text{ where } Y\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{m}\,\, \text{is compact, simply connected}.$$

My question is how to accurately describe the boundary of the image of $f.$ We know that from the Inverse Function Theorem that:
$$F(\partial\Omega)\subseteq\partial F(\Omega).$$
But it seems that "new" boundary can form, if we look at the limit:
$$g(y) = \lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x,y).$$
This limit exists and finite for any $y\in Y$ and
for the particular problem I am working on, $g(y)$ turns out to be piecewise constant i.e.,:
$$g(y) = \sum\limits_{s\in S}a_s\mathbf{1}_{\{X_s\}}(y)$$
where $Y = \cup_{s\in S}Y_s$ is a finite partition of $Y.$ So I am tempted to conclude:
$$\partial F(\Omega) = F(\partial\Omega)\cup\{a_s\vert\ s\in S \}.$$

However, numerical simulation *strongly* suggests that the line segments (or hyperplanes) joining the points $a_s$ also lie on the boundary of image of $f.$ So at this point, I want to prove something like for two limit points $a_s,a_t$:
$$\forall\alpha\in[0,1]: \alpha a_s + (1-\alpha)a_t\in\partial F(\Omega).$$

But none of the usual theorems about diffeomorphism I find is of direct help, as they deal with open sets or they are about holomorphic functions. However, my $\Omega$ is not open and my function is real.

Can someone point me to a nice reference that deals with results like this?

Comment: The inverse function theorem might be your friend

Comment: The sentence "We know that from the Inverse Function Theorem that..." Is actually quite false.

Comment: @MoisheKohan is it still false if the Jacobian is positive definite? Sorry, it was stated in the initial formulation but then I forgot to keep it in the new edit. $f$ has a positive definite Jacobian at all interior points.

Comment: What do you mean by "Jacobian", matrix or a number (the determinant)? One talks about positive definite matrices but positive numbers.

Comment: @MoisheKohan  I meant the first derivative matrix. Wikipedia says "Both the matrix and (if applicable) the determinant are often referred to simply as the Jacobian in literature."

Comment: Ok, the modified claim is still false. Maybe it is true assuming connectivity of the domain. But in any case, it does not follow from the Inverse Function Theorem.

Comment: yes, I can assume $Y$ is as nice as possible, simply connected, closed and bounded etc. But in that case why would not it follow from IVT?  IVT + positive Jacobian would not imply that $f$ sends interior points to interior points?

Comment: @dezdichado Try to write a careful proof and you will find out. At this point, your question is imprecise. You should edit it to include all the relevant definitions and assumptions.